# Stop criterion is Infinitive in Perceptron in Sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, perceptron

I read code in book "Hand-on Machine Learning in Sklearn and TensorFlow" by Aurelien Geron

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
per_clf = Perceptron(max_iter=100, tol=-np.infty, random_state=42)
```

As I understand in [this document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html)  about Perceptron method
**tol** argument is the stop criterion and the iteration will stop if

*loss > previous_loss - tol*

So with tol is negative infinitive(tol= -np.infty) the loss will always need so be huge to stop iteration.

And the epoch will always reach the *max_iter* in this situation.

Is my thinking right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iteration stops when $\text{loss} > \text{previous_loss} - \text{tol}$ that amounts to $\text{previous_loss} - \text{loss} < \text{tol}$.  $\text{previous_loss} - \text{loss} < \text{-np.infty}$ means $\text{previous_loss} + \text{np.infty} < \text{loss}$ which would be impossible and hence the epoch will always reach the `max_iter`.

Comment: Thank you to your confirm.

Comment: @TanPhan You are welcome!